# Why does it take so long to load the login items with "reopen when logging back in" enabled?

Tags: macos, startup, login-items

With OSX Lion 10.7 Apple has introduced **[resume](https://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/)**:

- Restore the state of the computer when shut down.
- Reopen the used windows of applications.

While both are quite useful, the option to *"reopen windows when loggin back in"* causes the login items to be reloaded with a significant delay.

Programs get restarted immediately. I can use them with their full functionally within seconds. But the login items take up to another half minute to start. I should probably mention that the boot process takes only sixteen seconds (power button → desktop).

On a 'clean' start the login items will load right after the desktop appears.

### Question

Why does it take so long to load menu-extras with "reopen when logging back in" enabled?

---

[**Update:** march 2013] This behavior is still persistent as of Mountain Lion 10.8.3.

Comment: I haven't noticed any significant difference in loading times between menu extras and application windows — both are slow, probably since I have so many open :)

Comment: @jtbandes Maybe I should edit the question. It's not just menu extras, but all of the login times which take so long to load in resume. In total I have fifth-teen  of them to load. On a 'clean' start they appear immediately.

Comment: 16 seconds? What kind of supercomputer do you have? I can only dream of this bootup time :) that's aside

Comment: @Michiel MBP early 2011 (2.2 GHz quad-core i7, Crucial m4 SSD)

Comment: It must be the SSD, cause I've got nearly the same configuration :-)

Comment: Ye I also got that SSD recently and got that booting time on 2009 MBP 13"

Comment: I see the same issue, but only *sometimes*, not every time. It might be worth testing with different applications (or a different number of applications) being restarted automatically. e.g. if there's a lot to do, the OS might delay login items pending CPU load, app responsiveness, or just a constant time for the number of apps...?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the login items get started *after* all the applications from the last session have started up. For example, an older version of Adium used to hang (due to no internet connection being available) for a few seconds after starting up, and as soon as Adium was responsive, the login items got started.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. All started applications in the dock are ready to use immediately. Maybe it's one of the login items?

Comment: Duh, for me it was specifically Adium (with an ICQ account) hanging when started without an internet connection (but apparently they fixed it in version 1.5). And after Adium is done staring, my login items start to appear in the menu bar. Maybe there's a hidden application that hangs on your Mac. Did you check the system log?

Comment: For me it was Chrome. It appeared ready but was still busy and delayed the Login Items. Please [duplicate](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) this [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/12225387) to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is iTunes syncing with iPhones etc. through the network, and the system waits for that to finish before it loads startup items.

Comment: Wireless iTunes sync is triggered by the iPhone, not by iTunes starting up.